# Fullscreen scrollable wrapper not browser compatible

Tags: html, css

I want to create a fullscreen div-element which is on top of a footer-element. The fullscreen div-element (`#wrapper`) should have a fullscreen background image and it should be scrollable to show the footer, which is placed in the background.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/tvuqzd17/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper { 
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 margin-bottom: 300px;
 overflow-x: auto;

 background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/nature_waterfall_summer_lake_trees_90400_3840x2160.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: -10;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
 <footer></footer>
```

But there are two problems:

1. It is working in chrome, but not in safari
2. The background image is not moving if scrolling down; it shouldn't be fixed like it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to make container always 100% height, and leave the footer to stand next.

Also, you don't need nackground fixed if you want the background image to move when scrolling

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/nature_waterfall_summer_lake_trees_90400_3840x2160.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<footer></footer>
```